# Issues with 'x is None', python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, null

So, I am trying to create a calculator where you input numbers into the console until you press enter without entering any numbers.

```
num1 = 0
num2 = 0
    if addec == ("Go"):
        adloop = 1
            print(para1, """ To exit,
press enter with no number

Please input the first number""", para1)
            sleep(1.5)
            num1 = float(input("--> "))

    while adloop == 1:
        try:
            num1 = num1 + num2
            print("Insert Number")
            num2 = float(input("--> "))

        except:
            if num2 is None:
                print("The answer is", num1)
            else:
                print(para1, """  ERROR: Invalid Response.

Please start again""")
```

The error comes in that even when num2 is null, the program skips past to the "else" statement and runs the ERROR line before restarting without spewing the answer back.
(the code is only a small extract, so if anything is missing it's probably somewhere else)

Thanks,

Comment: ["using a bare `except:` is almost never a good idea."](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#except)

Comment: your indentation is _wrong_ too

Comment: `num2` never loses its value. Reset it to `None` before asking for `input`

Comment: At no point in that program is `num2` *ever* set to `None`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks, that seems to have sorted it

Answer (score 0):

Along with `num2` never being set to `None`, there is no code to actually exit the loop (on success or failure.)  Also there are elements in the code that are dead ends example-wise (e.g. `addec`, `para1`, `sleep(1.5)`, multi-line strings, etc.) which you should weed out when presenting a runnable example about which you want to ask a question:

```
print("To exit, press enter with no number.")
print("Please input the first number:")
num1 = float(input("--> "))

num2 = 0

while True:
    try:
        num1 = num1 + num2
        num2 = None
        print("Insert Number")
        num2 = float(input("--> "))
    except ValueError:
        if num2 is None:
            print("The answer is", num1)
            break
        else:
            exit("ERROR: Invalid Response.  Please start again")
```

We can also turn this inside out so we also catch bad values for `num1`:

```
print("To exit, press enter with no number.")
print("Please input the first number:")

num2 = 0

try:
    num1 = float(input("--> "))

    while True:
        num1 = num1 + num2
        num2 = None
        print("Insert Number")
        num2 = float(input("--> "))
except ValueError:
    if num2 is None:
        print("The answer is", num1)
    else:
        exit("ERROR: Invalid Response.  Please start again")
```

**USAGE**

```
% python3 test.py
To exit, press enter with no number.
Please input the first number:
--> goat
ERROR: Invalid Response.  Please start again
%
```